# The method getMapLocationInfo result not UTF8?

Tags: android, google-maps

I've got a problem with this function :

```
JSONObject result = GeolocalisationHelper.getMapLocationInfo("Ingré");

public static JSONObject getMapLocationInfo(String address) {

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +address+"&ka&sensor=false");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```

In LogCat the result is : 
[image]

You can see an encoding problem with the city name...

Could you help me please ?
Thanks !

**EDITED**

Comment: and what the frak is GeolocalisationHelper?

Comment: Oups ! Look at my edit ;)

Comment: `while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }` omg, omg ... this code makes me blind ...  use: `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");`